# Count the number of element within each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I have this dataframe `df`, which includes `name` and `type` columns:

```
name   type
Jay    c1
Rand   c2
Hano   c3
Jay    c1
Jay    c2
Rand   c2
Roger  c1
Roger  c1
Roger  c3
```

The output should be like that (for each of the type, how many each name; inserted as a new column):

```
name   type   count
Jay    c1     2
Jay    c2     1
Rand   c2     2
Hano   c3     1
Roger  c1     2
Roger  c3     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
In [1060]: df.groupby(['name', 'type']).size().reset_index(name='count')
Out[1060]: 
    name type  count
0   Hano   c3      1
1    Jay   c1      2
2    Jay   c2      1
3   Rand   c2      2
4  Roger   c1      2
5  Roger   c3      1
```